# What's the best way to ensure uniqueness of FKs in all permutations?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a `Friendship` relation that maps two User's together.

Here are the two FKs:

1. `fk_friend_one_id`
2. `fk_friend_two_id`

I have a `UNIQUE INDEX` for `(fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id)` but you can insert the ids in both ways and it would still work:

```
INSERT INTO friendship (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO friendship (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id) VALUES (2, 1);
```

How should I enforce uniqueness in this case?

Here are some solutions I have thought of:

1. Just always insert in both order.
2. Ensure that `fk_friend_two_id` > `fk_friend_one_id`. Sadly this cannot be enforced in the db level with MySQL because `CHECK` does nothing.

Comment: #1 can save you a lot of UNION queries. And CHECK is supported in latest MySQL and MariaDB versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The other Answers are working too hard.  All it takes is a `UNIQUE` and some simple SQL code.)

If you have values $x and $y to insert into a table, then be sure to put them in in a canonical order:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (a, b)
    VALUES ( LEAST($x, $y),
             GREATEST($x, $y) )
```

And have

```
UNIQUE(a, b)   -- or, better yet, PRIMARY KEY(a,b)
```

Note that whether the values are (1,2) or (2,1), the only row that will be inserted is (1,2)

What should be done if you try to put both in?  One will go in as (1,2); the other will get an error on the `INSERT`.  You can have the error ignored via `INSERT IGNORE`.  If there are other columns that need setting, consider using `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`

Comment: This is really intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MySql 8.0.16 you can add a [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) that actually does something.

(Between MySql 5.7 & 8.0.16 you could add one, but it would just be ignored)

For MariaDb a working CHECK constraint was implemented since version 10.2.1. [Reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/)

So if your version supports it, then it could be something like this example:

> ```
> create table Friend (
>   id int primary key auto_increment, 
>   name varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into Friend (name) values
> ('John Doe'), ('Jane Shepard')
>
> create table Friendship (
>   id int primary key auto_increment,
>   fk_friend_one_id int not null,
>   fk_friend_two_id int not null,
>   CONSTRAINT chk_friend2_gt_friend1 check (fk_friend_two_id > fk_friend_one_id),
>   CONSTRAINT fk_friend_one_id foreign key (fk_friend_one_id) references Friend(id),
>   CONSTRAINT fk_friend_two_id foreign key (fk_friend_two_id) references Friend(id),
>   CONSTRAINT idx_friends unique index (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into Friendship (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id) value (2, 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> CONSTRAINT `chk_friend2_gt_friend1` failed for `mydb`.`Friendship`
> ```

> ```
> insert into Friendship (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id) value (1, 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> CONSTRAINT `chk_friend2_gt_friend1` failed for `mydb`.`Friendship`
> ```

> ```
> insert into Friendship (fk_friend_one_id, fk_friend_two_id) value (1, 2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from Friendship order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fk_friend_one_id | fk_friend_two_id
> -: | ---------------: | ---------------:
>  1 |                1 |                2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=00a48bfb49a57368ab593dc75748a81e)*

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with [stored procedures](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php) and [triggers](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php). You can try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE `friendship_check`(IN fk_friend_one_id INT, IN fk_friend_two_id INT)
BEGIN
    IF fk_friend_one_id < fk_friend_two_id THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on friendship failed';
    END IF;
END$
DELIMITER ;


-- before insert trigger
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `friendship_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Friendship`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL friendship_check(new.fk_friend_one_id,new.fk_friend_two_id);
END$
DELIMITER ;
```